# Firefox Float: Post Feed Overlapping Header Image

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, css-float, clearfix

I'm having this strange issue on a website I'm working on using a modified Wordpress Twenty Sixteen theme: http://olderbeast.com/

It looks fine on Chrome and Opera, but on Firefox and Edge the blog feed ignores the new header image and overlaps it at the top. I believe this is due to the float: left that the div#primary has, but I've tried multiple clearfixes and nothing has changed.

Am I missing something, or not implementing clearfix properly?

EDIT: Michael Coker solved it with making the image display:block and clear:both. Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a verifiable demo here on SO rather than linking to your website?

Comment: adding `#road-to-olderbeast { display: block; clear: both; }` seems to fix it.

Comment: That worked Michael, thanks! I didn't know if making a demo of the site would be too big.

Comment: Sweet, np. I can move that to an answer if you like and want to accept it. Not sure if you wanted to leave this up or close it.